# How to update a field of an element of nested Arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a document like below and I want to update a field, say RSSI, of an accessPoint with a given MAC and a given fingerId. Currently I'm achieving this via, first finding the index of the accessPoint and then updating its field. Is there any better way ?

here's a sample document

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d00d45bef388e16b9406b13"), 
    "x" : 7.2, 
    "y" : 4.5, 
    "visitTime" : NumberLong(1560337948058), 
    "gridNumber" : NumberInt(-1), 
    "fingerprints" : [
        {
            "accessPoints" : [
                {
                    "MAC" : "MAC5", 
                    "SSID" : "SSID3", 
                    "RSSI" : NumberInt(20)
                }, 
                {
                    "MAC" : "MAC6", 
                    "RSSI" : NumberInt(20)
                }
            ], 
            "orientation" : NumberInt(0), 
            "fingerId" : NumberInt(0)
        }
    ],
```

and here's what I'm currently doing :

```
 Query query = new Query(new Criteria().andOperator(
                Criteria.where(Fields._ID).is(new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId(obsId))),
                Criteria.where("fingerprints").elemMatch(Criteria.where("fingerId").is(fingerDoc.getId())),
                Criteria.where("fingerprints.accessPoints").elemMatch(Criteria.where("MAC").is(mac))

        ));

        int index = getIndexOfAP(collection,obsId, mac);

        if(index != -1) {
            Update update = new Update().set("fingerprints.$.accessPoints." + index + ".RSSI", newValue.getRSSI());
            UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, collection);
        }
```

I've also tried using `fingerprints.$.accessPoints.$.RSSI` and I get `too many $  error` any alternative solutions to using multiple $, other than redesigning the DB, would be appreciated.

- Note that here there is only one fingerprint here but in the real data there would be many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with considering the fact that MAC is unique in my case:

```
  BsonDocument bsonDocument = new BsonDocument();
        bsonDocument.append(Fields._ID,new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId(obsId)));
        bsonDocument.append("fingerprints.fingerId",new BsonInt32(fingerprintDoc.getFingerId()));


        mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection).updateMany(bsonDocument,
                new Document().append("$set", new Document().append("fingerprints.$.accessPoints.$[item].RSSI", newValue.getRSSI())),
                new UpdateOptions()
                        .arrayFilters(
                                Collections.singletonList( Filters.in("item.MAC",
                                        Collections.singletonList(mac)) ))
        );
```

in this way I first find the desired fingerprint with the given Id and update the accessPoint's RSSI that matches the mac, and that's what I was looking for